# How to append to a compressed file?

Tags: c++

I am writing a large file (uncompressed is ~3GB). I am doing this a few million rows at a time. I was using gzstream for both reading and writing to compressed files. Initially I tried using `ogzstream(fileName, ios::app)` but realised later that won't work. My question is without writing another wrapper like may be `agzstream`, can i just use ogzstream to keep writing to the same file?